# How to add error code along with validation messages through rules in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

We are creating postman collections for all of our end point built on the top of yii2. In all collections, we are using bdd scenarios where we need to test error messages and of course successes. We can compare with the returned error messages to get assertions passed but messages can be changed which eventually make our test fail.

So instead of comparing with string message, I want to compare it with error codes. but i don't know if it is possible to raise errors like exceptions which  can be used to test using codeception or endpoints with the tools like postman or swagger.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. To achieve my requirement i need to extend Yii2 validators where i overwrite "validateAttribute" method. Here i can raise required exception with the code. And this has also allowed me to pass exception type and code directly from the rules.

```
namespace common\components\validators;

use yii\base\InvalidArgumentException;

class RequiredValidator extends \yii\validators\RequiredValidator
{
  public $code;
  public $exception;

  public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
  {
    parent::validateAttribute($model, $attribute); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
     if($this->exception){
        throw new $exception($this->formatMessage($this->message, ['attribute' => $attribute]),$this->code);
     }
  }
}
```

This has allowed me to define rules like following.

```
public function rules(){
  return [
  ['param', RequiredValidator::className(), 'code' => 100102, 'exception' => 'UserCustomException']
];
}
```